# Java cooldown system

Tags: java

I've been trying to make a cooldown system in java given three variables,

- the cooldown time, for example 100 seconds,
- the click timestamp(when it was last clicked)
- the current timestamp.

I made it work before but it looks very complicated, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

My code to check if the click is on cooldown or not:

```
private boolean onCooldown(String playerUUID, int npcId, int cooldown) {
    boolean toReturn = false;
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss"); 
        Date savedTime;
        Date nowTime;
        String savedString = database.getTime(playerUUID, npcId);
        nowTime = df.parse(timeStamp);
        savedTime = df.parse(savedString);
        long diff = nowTime.getTime() - savedTime.getTime();
        long savedSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;  
        long savedMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;          
        long nowSeconds = cooldown  % 60;
        long nowMinutes = cooldown / 60 % 60;
        if (!((savedMinutes >= nowMinutes) && (savedSeconds >= nowSeconds))) {
            toReturn = true;
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toReturn = false;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Is there a better or easier way than this?

Cheers.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` will give the current time in nano seconds.  Save the first value externally from the method and keep getting the nanoTime each time the method is called until the threshold is met.  Then replace the old external nanoTime variable with the new time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (since you're looking for improvements to already working code).

Comment: Try creating a GUI using JavaFx. Also, JavaFx has a Timeline Class that would work nicely for this. You can start the timer on a button click and set the button to disable until the timer finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that stores the player's UUID and the current timestamp. Within the method you can then check if the map contains the player's key and if so check if the value stored and your desired cooldown is less/greater than the current time.

As [Craigr8806](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5799145/craigr8806) stated in the comments, I'd recommend using `System.nanoTime()` for the timestamps.

Comment: You should also add that aside from the obvious benefit of reduction in computation, there will be a significant reduction in memory usage as `System.nanoTime()` just returns a primitive `long` instead of a full DTO

Comment: I was using a HashMap before to store the time but it had a small downside which was the time it could be stored, since I am using this on a plugin for minecraft every time someone would do a reload of the server the HashMap would reset, and cooldowns of for example 172800 seconds(2 days) would be lost. But thank you and thanks @CraigR8806 too, I'll improve what I have!

Comment: You can store your Hashmap using [Bukkit's FileConfiguration](http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Configuration_API_Reference). Good luck!

Comment: What would be better performance wise, an SQLite database or a simple YML file?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the amount of data you have. Unless you need to store huge log files of e.g block locations, or chat history, I'd recommend using Bukkit's config.